# How to Get # URL value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

i cant use url Query https://example.com/?l=http://example2.com on my CloudFlare Worker server.

So, My question is, how to convert this JS script to work with https://example.com/#http://example2.com

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }      

var l = getUrlVars()["l"];
```

Based on jp-jee reply, this my script :

```
            <script>
var hash = window.location.hash;
    function change(){
        var txt = hash.replace("#", "");
        document.getElementById("url").value = txt;
    }
    
     </script>
          
           <input onclick="change()"  name="url" type="text" id="url" placeholder="enter url here" value="enter url here" />
           <button id="submit" onclick="submitURL()">Submit</button>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you want? Are you trying to pull out `http://example2.com` from `https://example.com/#http://example2.com`?

Comment: I just want to replace placeholder url text with url contain on #https://example.com

Comment: Would you please explain us what are you trying to achieve, in general terms, leaving aside the actual mechanics of where to read the data from, or how?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.hash` and remove the `#` character from the result.

For the URL `https://example.com/#http://example2.com`, `window.location.hash` evauates to `"#http://example2.com"`

Answer (score 1):

The `#` and text following it is known as the "fragment" or "hash". The `URL` class puts this in the property `.hash`.

However, there is a different problem: This text is not sent to the server in regular HTTP -- it is kept only in the browser. That means that you cannot see this value in Cloudflare Workers or any other server-side code. If you want to use `#` for navigation, you must implement your navigation on the client side, in the browser.

Comment: Yes that what i mean. I just want to replace url text value on client side form. Check my question update. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Cloudflare worker, it works like nodeJS or any other server-side application. This means you won't have access to `window.*` or `document.*` objects.

If you're trying to replace the placeholder, you should be using `.placeholder` and not `.value`, you can append this script in the document's head or body with your worker

```
<script>
var hash = window.location.href;
var txt = hash.replace("#", "");
document.getElementById("url").placeholder= txt;
</script>
```

So that as soon as your page loads the browser will execute the script & the placeholder will be modified.

Alternatively, You can also use Cloudflare worker to intercept & modify the response by changing your HTML template to

```
<input onclick="change()"  name="url" type="text" id="url" cloudflare_placeholder="enter url here" value="enter url here" />
```

Now from your worker, you can replace the text with

```
intercepted_html = intercepted_html.replace('cloudflare_placeholder=\"enter url here\"', 'placeholder=\"${host}/${pathname}\"')
```

Example on how to use Cloudflare worker to modify response. [Cloudflare response modification](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/modify-response/)